# Losing job while waiting for Blue Card

Tags: working-visas, eu, blue-card

I currently have a Fiktionsbescheinigung certificate that is valid for the next 6 months. If someone loses their job while their application for the blue card is under process, I wanted to ask:

1. How long one can stay in Germany?
2. Can they travel (leave and come back to the country) on this Fiktionsbescheinigung certificate?

Answer (score 1):

No one will bother you until you have your valid Fiktionsbescheinigung. But, you are under an obligation to communicate any changes to your working situation to the Ausländeramt, so you need to inform them that you no longer have the job under which you applied the card. They will inform you if anything regarding your stay changes.

You should be able to travel with that + expired Residence permit + passport without problems (to within and outside Europe). Best to confirm this information from the Amt.

Comment: It will depend on which type of **Fiktionsbescheinigung** (see Page 3, which checkbox is selected) the OP has. The first: § 81(3) sentance 1 (first application) does **not** allow travel to other Schengen countries when the person requires a visa (those that don't can travel based on their passport alone). Travel to other Schengen countries is allowed when the second or third checkbox is selected (existing permit is being renewed).